# my new created table appears in master(in system databases) instead of my created database in sql server

Tags: sql-server, database, create-table

my new created table appears in master(in system databases) instead of my created database in sql server.
here's my code:
create table patients(
id int not null ,
fname char(20) not null,
lname char(20) not null,
disease char(30),
primary key(id)
);[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KjdL.png)

Comment: take a look of the contextual database in the drop down list into the icon bar that shows you are in master database and not in your own db...

Answer (score 2):

Because you forget to begin with the

```
USE MyDatabase
```

Statement, that wil executes your DDL queries into the right db.

Comment: thanks alot.it worked :)